# scheduled task to open a PNG file

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

There is this picture, that I want to be shown every morning. I created a scheduled task, and in actions, I simply added a new action, that starts a program, and for the path of the program, I simply gave the path of my PNG file.

However, when the task runs (manually, or on schedule), it runs the `OpenWith.exe`, and that process is not shown, and I have no clue why it's hidden.

How can I show that PNG app, using the default viewer in task scheduler?

Answer (score 2):

Create script.bat file somewhere on your PC. Insert next text inside:
"%path-to-your-PNG-application" "%path-to-your-PNG-file"
Example:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\DefaultViewer.exe" "C:\Users\Owner\Pictures\pic.png"

Go to Task Scheduler, and create Basic Task. In the Program/script text box browse for your script.bat file.

After run the above script the program start but the Dos Windows still open. You can use the exit keyword to close it.
Example:
`start myProgram.exe param1
exit`